# not able to add Animal object with wildcard super of Dog

Tags: java

Had seen many examples related to use of `super` wildcard. Majority of them are with `Number` and `Integer` classes. However for my understanding I was trying the below code:

```
package util;
import java.util.*;
class Animal{
    void eat() {
    System.out.println("animal eats");  
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal{
    void eat() {
        System.out.println("dog eats");
    }
}
class Cat extends Animal{
    void eat() {
        System.out.println("cat eats");
    }
}
public class Test {

    public void addAnimal(List<? super Dog> list) {
        list.add(new Animal());//******* getting error here
        list.add(new Dog());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    List<? super Dog> lsDogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
    List<? super Dog> lsAnimals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    
}
}
```

as per the docs which I have understood `super` means we can add anything that is on right hand side or its super class. Here I created Dog class which extends Animal class. I can only add Dog type of objects and not Animal. Why is it not possible.. any specific reasons

Comment: I write `public void addAnimal(List<? super Dog> list) {` as per docs super allows adding super class object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<? super Dog>` says "this is a List that you can add a `Dog` to. You might be able to add a `Dog` because it is a `List<Dog>`, because it's a `List<Animal>`, or because it's a `List<Object>`."

You can't add an `Animal` to a `List<? super Dog>`, because your `Animal` could be any `Animal` subclass, e.g. a `Cat`, and then you may have a `Cat` in a `List<Dog>`.

```java
class Animal { void sound() {}}
class Cat extends Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<>();

        add(objects);
        add(animals);
        add(dogs);
        add(cats); // Error, must be a list we can add Dogs to

        addAnimal(objects);
        addAnimal(animals);
        addAnimal(dogs); // Error, must be a list which can contain any Animal
        
        useList(objects); // Error, must be a List of Animals
        useList(animals);
        useList(dogs);
        useList(cats);
    }

    public static void add(List<? super Dog> list) {
        list.add(new Dog());
    }

    public static void addAnimal(List<? super Animal> list) {
        list.add(new Dog());
        list.add(new Cat());
        for (Animal a : list) { // error, ? can be Object
            a.sound();
        }
    }
    
    // If we're consuming items from the list we use extends
    public static void useList(List<? extends Animal> list) {
        list.add(new Animal()); // error, ? is a specific but unknown subclass of Animal
        for (Animal a : list) {
            a.sound();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so List<? super Dog> means it can accept either list of Dog, Animal or Object. But can add only Dog. If this is so.. then how do I traverse this wild card super list.. means If it accept List<Animal> then what should be the reference type in for loop

Comment: I'm not sure what for loop you mean, in which context. Please edit your question.

Comment: I've added an example using a loop, might be what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

The `?` means that we don't know what the class is but it is a definite class.

`? super of Dog` means that ? is something that is a parent of dog. For your example you have { Object, Animal, Dog }. So your `?` can be any of those 3 classes.

You can add to the list as long as what every you add can be cast to `?`.

Can you add a Dog to the list? Yes because Dog can be cast to **any** Object, Animal, Dog.

Can you add an Animal to the list? No, because Animal cannot be cast to Dog.

Since Dog is the most specified it is the **boundary** that we compare against. You can add any Dog or class that extends Dog.